# Reload random div content every x seconds

Tags: php, html, random, reload

I've got a div that randomly shows 1 of 10 files on each pageload. I'd like this to reload on a set time interval of 8 seconds, giving me a different one of the 10 files each reload.

I've read a few of the related questions using jQuery `.load` as a solution but this doesn't quite work with my code since I'm not loading a specific file each time.

This is my div content:

```
<div id="tall-content">

 <?

  $random = rand(1,10);

  include 'tall-files/' . $random . '.php';

 ?>

</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you load a php file that will use your code above via jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only PHP to accomplish this is impractical. This example uses jQuery and PHP.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#div").load("random.php");
     var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
         $("#div").load('random.php');
     }, 8000);
     $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

random.php

```
$pages = array("page1.php", "page2.php", "page3.php", "page4.php", "page5.php");

$randompage = $pages[mt_rand(0, count($pages) -1)];

include ($randompage);
```

Answer (score 0):

while using PHP to generate the random content, you cannot get the div to reload that content without refreshing the entire page.

A better solution is to use AJAX. You can store that PHP code that's inside the div container as a seperate file, and use ajax to request that php file. You can also set an infinite loop to request the php file every 8 seconds. Here is a sample, but you will need to re-code it to your specification:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function ajaxFunction(){
var ajaxRequest;
try{ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();} catch (e){try{ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");} catch (e) {try{ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");} catch (e){alert("Error: Browser/Settings conflict");return false;}}}
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            document.getElementById('tall-content').innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    var url = "random.php";
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
//-->
</script>
```

The only missing part is the refresh timer, since I do not program a lot in javascript I can't help you there. But the goal in this case is to create a file "random.php", put the random generator there, and use this script above to make an ajax request to random.php, which will place the output of that php script in the div container with the id of "tall-content". So really, you need to create another javascript which loops indefinitely calling the function "ajaxFunction()" and wait 8000 milliseconds .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this while the user is sitting back in the chair on your page, the answer is javascript.

You could use this function for example.

```
    function recrusive_timeout_function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                    recrusive_timeout_function();
            }, 8000);
    }
```

If you want to include a php file in that div (which outputs some html). Ajax is your friend and JQuery as a user friendly and easy to use javascript framework which handles your thinks really nice.